# interdependent graphQl types

Tags: javascript, graphql

I would like to design a graphQl schema in which two types are interdependent. basically I have a database structure in which:

`User.hasOne(Search)`

I would like to be able to make graphQl queries like this one:

```
// note that 'me' has User type
// search has Search type
query{
  me{
    email,
    search{
      content,
      user{
       id
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So, you see that we request a `User`, its `Search` and the `User` owning  this `Search` (OK in this case this is not usefull at all).

Here is what could be the definition of the `UserType`:

```
import {
  GraphQLObjectType as ObjectType,
  GraphQLID as ID,
  GraphQLString as StringType,
  GraphQLNonNull as NonNull,
  GraphQLInt as IntType,
} from 'graphql';

const UserType = new ObjectType({
  name: 'User',
  fields: {
    id: { type: new NonNull(ID) },
    username: { type: StringType },
    search: {
      type: SearchType,
      resolve(user){
        return user.getSearch();
      }
    },
  },
});
```

Here is my definition of the `SearchType`:

```
const SearchType = new ObjectType({
  name: 'Search',
  fields: {
    id: { type: new NonNull(ID) },
    user: {
      type: UserType,
      resolve(search){
        return search.getUser();
      }
    },
    content: { type: StringType },
  },
});
```

Unfortunatelly this does not work, I guess due to the interdependence between `UserType` ans `SearchType`, and I get the following error:

```
User.search field type must be Output Type but got: function type() {
  return _SearchType2.default;
}
```

Is there any way I could implement this inter dependency between `User` and `Search`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From this page http://graphql.org/graphql-js/type/#graphqlobjecttype
See how PersonType is dependent on itself?

```
var PersonType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Person',
  fields: () => ({
    name: { type: GraphQLString },
    bestFriend: { type: PersonType },
  })
});
```

The thing you are looking for is

```
fields: () => ({
...
})
```